# How can a rust `new` method know which generic type of structure to return?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and one thing didn't seem right

```
let vector: VecDeque<u32> = VecDeque::new();
```

How can the `new` method know which type of `VecDeque` to return? Could be `VecDeque<T>` for any `T`. I come from C++ where, if there were a static `new` method it'd have to be templated and I'd have to call like this: `CppObject<int> cppObject = CppObject<int>()` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust does a lot of type inference. In this case, it knows to call `VecDeque::<u32>::new()` because you explicitly specified that you want to assign it to a variable of type `VecDeque<u32>` and the only way you can get there is if you call the associated method `new()` on exactly the type `VecDeque<u32>`.

Note that if you did not annotate the type of `vector`, it would fail to compile:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let vector = VecDeque::new();
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `std::collections::VecDeque<T>`
 --> src/main.rs:4:18
  |
4 |     let vector = VecDeque::new();
  |         ------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`
  |         |
  |         consider giving `vector` the explicit type `std::collections::VecDeque<T>`, where the type parameter `T` is specified
```

But the compiler will also successfully infer the type if there are operations afterwards that make clear that `VecDeque` elements are of type `u32`:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut vector = VecDeque::new(); // type not yet known
    vector.push_back(123);            // append untyped integer, type not yet known

    let expected: u32 = 123;
    assert_eq!(vector[0], expected); // A-ha! vector[0] returns T
                                     // and T is compared with u32,
                                     // so it must follow that T is u32
}
```